# How to clear DatePicker in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to clear Datepicker value on click of checkbox. Using below code input text value gets set to null; but it shows the date selected from datepicker in input text. In this case how to reset datepicker?

```js
$scope.SetFromDate = function (FromDate) {
    if (validateDateFormat(FromDate)) {
        $scope.FromDate = FromDate;
    } 
};

$scope.ChangeDateAll = function () {
    if ($scope.FromDateAll) {
        $scope.FromDate = '';
    } else {
        $scope.FromDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD MMM YYYY");
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="FromDateAll" ng-change="ChangeFromDateAll()" />
<datepicker date-format="dd MMM yyyy">
<input type="text" ng-model="FromDate" ng-enter="SetFromDate(FromDate)" ng-change="SetFromDate(FromDate);" /> 
</datepicker>
```

Comment: Is this datePicker an AngularJS component?
Have you tried $scope.$applyAsync() after `$scope.FromDate = '';`?

Comment: DatePicker is not an AngularJS component.

Comment: $scope.$applyAsync()  does not work